# Trigger a clean shutdown of a C application on Linux

Tags: c, linux, kill, shutdown

Is it possible to trigger a "clean" shutdown of an application written in C on a Linux system? By "clean" I mean a solution for de-initializing interfaces, etc.. Like a destructor of an object in C++, but for my C application.

I know that it is possible to shutdown services with systemd, but my application is not a service. I'm using a systemd.service to start my application, but the application itself, as far as I understand the systemd services, is considered a oneshot (there is an initialization at the beginning and then it goes into a while (1) loop).

Is it possible to break out of the loop with a systemd or similar Linux functionality? What is the "standard" solution to such a problem?

```
int main (int argc, char **argv){
  // ... some initialization
  printf("Warming up!\n);

  while(keepRunning){
    // do stuff
    printf("Running!!\n");
  }
  // de-initialize
  printf("By by\n");
}
```

I would expect systemd to change the value of keepRunning to 0. But I think that would be too easy.

Comment: What is the purpose of the program? What problem is it supposed to solve? How long should it run? What is the condition for it to end?

Comment: Maybe `man 3 signal` is of help.

Comment: It calculates pi until the system tells it to stop (something like systemds ExecStop?), then it prints how many digits it was able to calculate and how long it took. The condition for it to end would be a system shutdown or another application trying to update the executable file.

Comment: The exact purpose of this application would be a longer essay, therefore the summary with calculating pi.

Comment: Well for system shutdown I think that there's really no need to do anything, it should just let itself be killed (the result isn't interesting at that moment anyway). To present the current result you could catch one of the `SIGUSR1` or `SIGUSR2` signals, and then continuing your processing. And for exiting with presenting the current result how about `SIGINT`?

Answer (score 0):

- Set up signal handlers (without the `SA_RESTART` flag in their sigaction's `.sa_flags`) for the signals that should kill the app without skipping cleanup code.
- Make the signal handlers set an atomic/`sig_atomic_t` flag (or clear your `keepRunning` flag, but usually the other way around so that you can use it to take note signal number).
- When you get an `EINTR` or at any other time, inspect the flag and start failing if it is set.
  (i.e., start returning failure-signalling return values if in C or maybe throw an exception in C++.)